# Cant able to remove the .swp files from the ubuntu 14.04 PC

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal, swap

Cant remove the .swp file from disk it showing no files, how can i remove that ?
 [image]

Comment: Try the same command using `sudo`.

Comment: same result - > No such file or directory when trying with sudo

Comment: Are you sure the file is still there? Can you list the files from the directory with permissions? Just in case.

Comment: After production server restart its gone, but that files are listing out when i run "locate wkhtml" before restarting server.

Comment: do the following: 1/ answer your own question (and accept the answer) that the file is gone after a restart.  2/ run the command `sudo updatedb`.  If you want to know why look around the site first before asking a duplicate question!  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby but that file exist in the  production until its restart. more than 10 times that rm command i executed, and after "locate" command file is listing out there !

Comment: I'll post an answer and you can accept that one then as the comments are too small to fully explain this.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly normal that `locate` still finds a file after it's been deleted as `locate` uses a database to perform its search. (and that's why it's so much faster then `find`).

**An example:**

Go to a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the following command:

```
touch errakesh123.txt
```

Now do an `ls`.  There is now a file called `errakesh123.txt` isn't it?  Now do:

```
locate errakesh123.txt
```

And you will see the file is not there!  **:-(**

Now type:

```
sudo updatedb
```

Now again:

```
locate errakesh123.txt
```

It's there!  (as the `sudo updatedb` updated the location DB)

*The same thing happened with the swp file.*

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as both of our reputations will go up!  ;-)